# Ajax call to php for csv file manipulation hangs

Tags: php, ajax, optimization

Okay so I have a button. When pressed it does this:

**Javascript**

```
$("#csv_dedupe").live("click", function(e) {
    file_name = 'C:\\server\\xampp\\htdocs\\Gene\\IMEXporter\\include\\files\\' + $("#IMEXp_import_var-uploadFile-file").val();
    $.post($_CFG_PROCESSORFILE, {"task": "csv_dupe", "file_name": file_name}, function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }, "json")
});
```

This ajax call gets sent out to this:

**PHP**

```
class ColumnCompare {
    function __construct($column) {
        $this->column = $column;
    }

    function compare($a, $b) {
        if ($a[$this->column] == $b[$this->column]) {
            return 0;
        }
        return ($a[$this->column] < $b[$this->column]) ? -1 : 1;
    }
}

if ($task == "csv_dupe") {
    $file_name = $_REQUEST["file_name"];

    // Hard-coded input
    $array_var = array();
    $sort_by_col = 9999;
    //Open csv file and dump contents
    if(($handler = fopen($file_name, "r")) !== FALSE) {
        while(($csv_handler = fgetcsv($handler, 0, ",")) !== FALSE) {
            $array_var[] = $csv_handler;
        }
    }
    fclose($handler);

    //copy original csv data array to be compared later
    $array_var2 = $array_var;

    //Find email column
    $new = array();
    $new = $array_var[0];
    $findme = 'email';
    $counter = 0;
    foreach($new as $key) {
        $pos = strpos($key, $findme);
        if($pos === false) {
            $counter++;
        }
        else {
            $sort_by_col = $counter;
        }
    }
    if($sort_by_col === 999) {
        echo 'COULD NOT FIND EMAIL COLUMN';
        return;
    }

    //Temporarily remove headers from array
    $headers = array_shift($array_var);
    // Create object for sorting by a particular column
    $obj = new ColumnCompare($sort_by_col);
    usort($array_var, array($obj, 'compare'));

    // Remove Duplicates from a coulmn
    array_unshift($array_var, $headers);
    $newArr = array();
    foreach ($array_var as $val) {
        $newArr[$val[$sort_by_col]] = $val;
    }
    $array_var = array_values($newArr);

    //Write CSV to standard output
    $sout = fopen($file_name, 'w');
    foreach ($array_var as $fields) {
        fputcsv($sout, $fields);
    }
    fclose($sout);

    //How many dupes were there?
    $number = count($array_var2) - count($array_var);    
    echo json_encode($number);
}
```

This php gets all the data from a csv file. Columns and rows and using the fgetcsv function it assigns all the data to an array. Now I have code in there that also dedupes (finds and removes a copy of a duplicate) the csv files by a single column. Keeping intact the row and column structure of the entire array.

The only problem is, even though it works with small files that have 10 or so rows that i tested, it does not work for files with 25,000.

Now before you say it, I have went into my php.ini file and changed the max_input, filesize, max time running etc etc to astronomical values to insure php can accept file sizes of upwards to 999999999999999MB and time to run its script of a few hundred years.

I used a file with 25,000 records and execute the script. Its been two hours and fiddler still shows that a http request has not yet been sent back. Can someone please give me some ways that I can optimize my server and my code?

I was able to use that code from a user who helped my in another question I posted on how to even do this initially. My concern now is even though I tested it to work, I want to know how to make it work in less than a minute. Excel can dedupe a column of a million records in a few seconds why cant php do this?

Comment: I would suggest you to use something like exec function http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php  to achieve you goal.

Comment: what do you see in firebug/chrome dev tools?

Comment: Thanks for the input. I don't think opening up an external program even excel would be desirable in this scenario.

Comment: Hey, did you try to split your array? Like in [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php#78058) from php.net

Comment: No errors besides negligible CSS errors.

Comment: Split the headers from the rest of the body? How would that help optimize procedure? 1 row seems negligible enough to not have to worry about.

Comment: SO I just did a test with 200 or so rows. and... its been 15 minutes and still nothing. This does not look good. Can anyone help? :/

Comment: @SofianeMerah, the trick is to answer when people offer help :-(

Comment: Sorry Terry I just got off work 0_0

Answer (score 0):

Sophie, I assume that you are not experienced at writing this type of application because IMO this isn't the way to approach this.  So I'll pitch this accordingly.

When you have a performance problem like this, you really need to binary chop the problem to understand what is going on.  So step 1 is to decouple the PHP timing problem from AJAX and get a simple understanding of why your approach is so unresponsive.  Do this using a locally installed PHP-cgi or even use your web install and issue a header('Context-Type: text/plain' ) and dump out microtiming of each step.  How long does the CSV read take, ditto the sort, then nodup, then the write?  Do this for a range of CSV file sizes going up by 10x in rowcount each time.

Also do a memory_get_usage() at each step to see how you are chomping up memory. Because your approach is a real hog and you are probably erroring out by hitting the configured memory limits -- a phpinfo() will tell you these.

The read, nodup and write are all o(N), but the sort is o(NlogN) at best and o(N<sup>2</sup>) at worst.  Your sort is also calling a PHP method per comparison so will be *slow*.

What I don't understand is why you are even doing the sort, since your nodup algo does not make use of the fact that the rows are sorted.

(BTW, the sort will also sort the header row inline, so you need to unshift it *before* you do the sort if you still want to do it.)

There are other issue that you need to think about such as

- Using a raw parameter as a filename makes you vulnerable to attack. Better to fix the patch relative to, say DOCROOT/Gene/IMEXporter/include and enforce some grammar on the file names.
- You need to think about atomicity of reading and rewriting large files as a response to a web request -- what happen if two clients make the request at the same time.
- Lastly you compare this to Excel, well load and saving Excel files can take time, and Excel doesn't have to scale to respond to 10s or 100s or users at the same time.  In a transactional system you typically use a D/B backend for this sort of thing, and if you are using a web interface to compute heavy tasks, you need to accept the Apache (or equiv server) hard memory and timing constraints and chop your algos and approach accordingly.

Comment: Okay I'm actually really tired right now but I am really impressed with the post. Its been a long day so I'm going to hit the haystack and in the morning I should have a good chance you read your answer carefully. Thanks for the input!

Comment: Ping back any Qs.   I'll be happy to take you thro any points.  :-)